# Extracting Polygons from Online Map

Tags: web-scraping, vector, gis

The below linked map contains a number of layers which I would like to be able to extract as polygons [if possible]. I've not previously done any web-scraping and realise that doing so in regards to the geographic data on this system represents a significant challenge.

Ideally I would only want to extract the data relating to the 'Shopping Local Centre' category.
Happy to try to use Phython or R to achieve such, just wondered if anyone had any ideas.....

[image: bolton council policy map]

Comment: Hi, you haven't mentioned what program you will be viewing the polygons in. And the link you have is just a *.png image. I have cobbled together an answer for you based off assumptions from your question.

Answer (score 0):

Web scraping (using [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), for example) would get you the HTML objects from a webpage. You would need basic knowledge of Python for this.

Or you could avoid that by going this route:

- With [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/) and Geofabrik you can gather retail location polygons and their attributes of a given area.
- Use [Geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/) to download your area of interest in *.shp (shapefile) format. It looks like you're in Greater Manchester, so I navigated to the download page [here](http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/great-britain/england/greater-manchester.html) (it's a 50MB file for the greater-manchester-latest-free.shp.zip).
- Once you download that, open it in QGIS and you'll see in the attributes it has retail locations.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That site is using WMS to display the map (I work for the company that makes iShare) so there is no vector content for you to **scrape** as it works entirely with images.

The easiest way to get the data would be to ask the council to provide it, you  might need to make it a freedom of information request but they should be happy to provide the data in a usable GIS format.